# Fragment not attached to activity after commit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm working with `Android Fragment` and I got an issue when calling `getString` method. It throws an exception

`10-12 07:43:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2425): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.TestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TestFragment{2c691b80 id=0x7f070015} not attached to Activity`

My code is the following code in my `Activity`:

```
public void addFragment(IFragment fragment)
{
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.add(R.id.dual_layout_pane, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        if (fragment.getActionBarTitle() != null) setTitle( fragment.getActionBarTitle() );
}
```

And in my `Fragment class`:

```
@Override
public String getActionBarTitle()
{
    return getString(R.string.login_title);
}
```

The error occurs on that line `return getString(R.string.login_title);`.

Is there a way to solve that kind of issue ?

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve that kind of issue ?

Delay your title change until `onAttach()` of the fragment. A `FragmentTransaction` is asynchronous; it will not be attached by the time `commit()` returns.

There is a function however, `commitNow()` that will attach the fragment right away.